# Why it's not required to use closure when using let(ES6)?

Tags: ecmascript-6

```
//A.Using let
var list = document.getElementById('list');

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Item ' + i));

    item.onclick = function(ev) {
       console.log('Item ' + i + ' is clicked.');
    };
    list.appendChild(item);
}


//B. Using var
// to achieve the same effect with 'var'
// you have to create a different context
// using a closure to preserve the value
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Item ' + i));

    (function(i){  
        item.onclick = function(ev) {
            console.log('Item ' + i + ' is clicked.');
        };
    })(i);
    list.appendChild(item);
}
```

Question:

As in section B, a closure is used to preserve the value for `i`, but closure is not needed in section A where `let` is used. How does `let` helps to preserve the value of `i`?
Thank you.

Comment: *"a closure is used to preserve the value for `i`"* **No!** *Closures* have nothing to do with the *solution*. The important part is that you are *executing* a function (in each iteration) and thus creating a new *scope* (per iteration). Whether or not the function is a closure is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `let` defines a new copy of `item` for each iteration of the `for` loop.  It creates a separate variable for you automatically in each iteration of the `for` loop so you don't have to do that manually by creating the closure.

Variables defined with `let` are block scoped.  So, each iteration of your `for` loop is a new block and thus a new definition of `let item`.

When you use `let` in the declaration of a `for` loop, as in:

```
for (let i = 1; ....)
```

then you also get a new copy of `i` for each iteration of the `for` loop and again, you don't have to use a closure to preserve that value within the `for` loop - that is done for you automatically.

Comment: Oh.. that's right.. thank you for the quick response :)